# Why doesn't the the search engine added by an extension show the "Make default" in the pop-up menu?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created an extension with values like those at the bottom of this post. The problem is that, if I set `is_default` to `true`, then the search engine is set as the default engine and the user cannot change it to other engines like Bing or Yahoo.  If I set `is_default` to `false`, then the search engine appears in the "Other search engines" list, but the three-dot button shows an empty pop-up menu, so the user cannot make manually set it as the default search engine.

[image]

This is weird, because other search engines in the list, that have been added not by an extension, shows a pop-up menu that has "Make default", so that users can make it as the default search engine when they want.

[image]

Is this a bug? Or an intended behaviour? If it is an intended behaviour, it looks quite weird to me. Why prohibiting the user from switching back and fourth among the stock search engines and the search engines added by an extension?

```
  "chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "search_provider": {
      "name": "Fake Engine",
      "search_url": "https://www.test.com/search?q={searchTerms}",
      "keyword": "fake",
      "favicon_url": "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
      "is_default": false,
      "encoding": "UTF-8"
    }
```

Comment: https://crbug.com/100495

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. I read the rationale that "It is not allowed because Chrome cannot handle a situation that the extension is removed later" , but that does not seem to make sense, because I can make it the default engine by setting `is_default` true. Also, even if so, I think it should have shown disabled entries in the pop-up menu instead of showing an empty pop-up menu. But, oh well, what can I do. I think I would have to set `is_default` to `true`, then.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me as well so if you got time consider posting a feature request there. This time another developer may have a look.